# Python and Pandas versions change how a number is interpreted after DataFrame read

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 environments:

**Environment #1 (old):**

- Python 3.7.5
- Pandas 0.23.4

**Environment #2 (new):**

- Python 3.8.10
- Pandas 1.3.4

When I load the same CSV file by doing `pd.read_csv('name_of_my_csv_file.csv', delimiter=';', dtype=str)` in both of the environments I noticed that Python or Pandas misinterpret some (not all of them, just about ~12 rows out of 50 000 rows) numbers.
In **Environment #1 (old)** the misinterpretation of a number looks like this `7546.168415200001`, where in reality the number in the Excel file is `7546.1684152`. **Environment #2 (new)** interprets the number correctly, that is, as `7546.1684152`.

```
>>> amount_old
7546.168415200001
>>>
>>> amount_new
7546.1684152
>>>
>>> # Types of both numbers from DataFrame
>>> type(amount_old)
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>>
>>> type(amount_new)
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>>
```

Based on this, I have 2 questions:

1. What causes this difference?
2. How do I make sure, that in **Environment #2 (new)** I get the same number as in **Environment #1 (old)**? That is, with the `00001` appended to it at the end? The reason I need the **Environment #2 (new)** match the **Environment #1 (old)'s** value is, that I have a test that compares the hash of the DataFrame, which, fails because of these different numbers. The hashes, in both cases, are created by this command: `pd.util.hash_pandas_object(my_dataframe_from_excel)`. Then, the hashes are compared in the test which fails because even the slightest change in the number causes the hash to be different.

**EDIT:** I'm not using `pd.read_excel()` but `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: Use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) from numpy to check if float numbers are equals within a tolerance.

Comment: Have you tried using `converters` for the required column. Also,  you can go through the documentation for `read_excel` function and look for [description](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) on `engine` and `converters` in arguments.

Comment: I think @AnuragReddy is pointing you in the right direction. Looking at the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel) for version 0.23.4, you can see that the engine used there was `xlrd`. In version 1.3.4, that same engine is used only for files with `xls` extension, while `openpyxl` is used for `xlsx`, as in your case. Probably that is where the problem comes from. To solve it try to set `engine="xlrd"`

Comment: @gionni and @AnuragReddy - thank you, but that does not work. When specifying `engine="xlrd"` it returns this error in pandas version 1.3.4: `Unknown engine: xlrd (valid options are dict_keys(['c', 'python', 'python-fwf']))`

Comment: That looks strange, what command are you running? It should be something like `pd.read_excel('name_of_my_excel.xlsx', engine="xlsr")`. It should give you this error `ValueError: Your version of xlrd is 2.0.1. In xlrd >= 2.0, only the xls format is supported. Install openpyxl instead.` because the file is not in .xls format

Comment: Oh... Sorry... I was so took by the issue that I didn't write it correctly. I'm using a CSV file as input -> so it looks like this: `pd.read_csv('name_of_my_csv_file.csv', , delimiter=';', dtype=str)`. I apologize. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at the end it seems like an issue with representation of float objects which, in the environment #1 (old) (described in my question above) was misinterpreted. The environment #2 (new)'s values are actually correct. That means, that we will need to adjust the tests to actually match the new environment's output instead of the old environment's output.

Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
To ensure your dataframe is loaded without any interpretation, use `dtype=object` in your 2 environments:

Documentation of [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) (Pandas 0.23.4) about `dtype`:

> Use object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not interpret dtype

---

Use `np.close`:

```
import numpy as np

amount_old = 7546.168415200001
amount_new = 7546.1684152

>>> amount_old == amount_new
False

>>> np.isclose(amount_old, amount_new)
True
```

With dataframes:

```
df_old = pd.DataFrame({'amount': [7546.168415200001]})
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'amount': [7546.1684152]})

>>> df_old['amount'] == df_new['amount']
0    False
Name: amount, dtype: bool

>>> np.isclose(df_old['amount'], df_new['amount'])
array([ True])

# Or without np.isclose
>>> df_old['amount'].sub(df_new['amount']).abs() <= 1e-6
0    True
Name: amount, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not what I am looking for. This only compares the value, row by row. But I need to make sure that all the numbers in environment #2 (new) match the numbers from the environment #1 (old) so that once I use the `pd.util.hash_pandas_object()` it returns the same hash

Comment: So use `read_excel` with `dtype=object` and you will have the same environment.